# Removing value from a DataFrame column which repeats over 15 times

Tags: python

I'm working on forex data like this:

```
     0                      1       2       3
1  AUD/JPY  20040101 00:01:00.000  80.598  80.598
2  AUD/JPY  20040101 00:02:00.000  80.595  80.595
3  AUD/JPY  20040101 00:03:00.000  80.562  80.562
4  AUD/JPY  20040101 00:04:00.000  80.585  80.585
5  AUD/JPY  20040101 00:05:00.000  80.585  80.585
```

I want to go through column 2 and 3 and remove the rows in which the value is repeated for more than 15 times in a row. So far I managed to produce this piece of code:

```
price = 0
drop_start = 0
counter = 0
df_new = df

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if r.iloc[2] != price:
        if counter >= 15:
            df_new = df_new.drop(df_new.index[drop_start:i])
        price = r.iloc[2]
        counter = 1
        drop_start = i
    if r.iloc[2] == price:
        counter = counter + 1

price = 0
drop_start = 0
counter = 0
df = df_new

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if r.iloc[3] != price:
        if counter >= 15:
            df_new = df_new.drop(df_new.index[drop_start:i])
        price = r.iloc[3]
        counter = 1
        drop_start = i
    if r.iloc[3] == price:
        counter = counter + 1

print(df_new.info())

df_new.to_csv('df_new.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Unfortunately when I check the output file there are some mistakes, there are some weekends which have not been removed by the program. How should I build my algorithm, so it removes the duplicated values correctly?

First 250k rows of my initial dataset is available here: https://ufile.io/omg5h

The output of this program for that sample data is available here:
https://ufile.io/2gc3d

You can see that in the output file the rows 6931+ were not succesfully removed:
[image]

Comment: maybe you could create a sample initial data set and then the desired data set with expected output. That way it would be easier for me to try to figure out what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is that, you are not holding specific `counter` values for the row values, but rather increment the counter through the loop. This causes the result to be false I believe. Also, the comparison `r.iloc[2] != price` also does not make sense because you are changing the value of price every iteration, so if there are elements between the duplicates, this check do not serve a proper function. I wrote a small code to copy the behavior you asked for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0.5, 2.5],[0,1, 2],[0,1.5,2.5 ],[0,2, 3],[0,2, 3],[0,3, 4], 
[0,4, 5]],columns = ['A','B','C'])

df_new = df
dict = {}

print('Initial DF')
print(df)
print()

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    counter = dict.get(r.iloc[1])
    if counter == None:
        counter = 0
    dict[r.iloc[1]] = counter + 1
    if dict[r.iloc[1]] >= 2:
        df_new = df_new[df_new.B != r.iloc[1]]

print('2nd col. deleted DF')
print(df_new)
print()

df_fin = df_new
dict2 = {}

for i, r in df_new.iterrows():
    counter = dict2.get(r.iloc[2])
    if counter == None:
        counter = 0
    dict2[r.iloc[2]] = counter + 1
    if dict2[r.iloc[2]] >= 2:
        df_fin = df_fin[df_fin.C != r.iloc[2]]

print('3rd col. deleted DF')
print(df_fin)
```

Here, I hold the `counter` value for each unique value in the rows of column 2 and 3. Then, according to the threshold(which is 2 in this case) I remove the rows which are exceeding the threshold. I first eliminate values according to the 2nd column, then forward this modified array to the next loop and eliminate values according to the 3rd column and finish the process.